# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'image')

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, django

```
import React from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import { Row, Col, Image, ListGroup, Button, Card } from 'react-bootstrap'
import Rating from '../components/Rating'
import products from '../products'


function ProductScreen({ match }) {
    const product = products.find((p) => p._id === match.params.id)
    return (
        <div>
            <Link to='/' className='btn btn-light my-3'>Go Back</Link>
        <Row>
            <Col md={6}>
                 <Image src={product.image} alt={product.name} fluid />
            </Col>

            <Col md={3}>
                <ListGroup variant="flush">
                    <ListGroup.Item>
                        <h3>{product.name}</h3>
                    </ListGroup.Item>

                    <ListGroup.Item>
                        <Rating value={product.rating} text={'${product.numReviews} reviews'} color={'#f8e825'} ></Rating>
                        </ListGroup.Item>
                    <ListGroup.Item>
                        Price: ₹{product.price}
                    </ListGroup.Item>

                    <ListGroup.Item>
                        Description: {product.description}
                    </ListGroup.Item>
                </ListGroup>
            </Col>
            
            <Col md={3}>
                <Card>
                    <ListGroup variant="flush">
                        <ListGroup.Item>
                            <Row>
                                <Col>Price:</Col>
                                <Col>
                                    <strong>{product.price}</strong>
                                </Col>
                            </Row>
                        </ListGroup.Item>
                        
                        <ListGroup.Item>
                            <Row>
                                <Col>Status:</Col>
                                <Col>
                                   {product.countInStok > 0 ? 'In Stock' : 'Out of Stock'}
                                </Col>
                            </Row>
                        </ListGroup.Item>

                        <ListGroup.Item>
                            <Button className='btn-block' type='button'> add to Cart </Button>
                        </ListGroup.Item>

                    </ListGroup>
                </Card>
            </Col>
        </Row>
    </div>
);
}

export default ProductScreen
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zzpw.png)

Comment: `products.find` does not find a match so returns `undefined`

Comment: You can do like this product?.image  so that it will check whether product is undefined or not.

Comment: Also it will be better to render the parent div conditionally.like

{product && <div> ... </div>}

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed in comment, your `products` variable has value `undefined`, hence your code fails.
Its always recommended and good practice to guard your code and avoid failures. There are multiple ways to guard yourself from these sitations. [Optional chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining), or [logical &&](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND).

So you could use something like:
`return products && <div>...</div>;` or for some cases you would like to show loader if you fetch data:
`return !products ? 'Loading...' : <div>...</div;`. Or you can use `products?.myProp1` on every place where your products variable appear. It can be cumbersome to repeat the same stuff and maybe you wish to guard/handle it differently.

Answer (score 0):

product is undefined so you can't read any properties of it. to prevent happening error check the value of it before render:

```
if(!product)
    return <></>
return (
    <div>
        <Link to='/' className='btn btn-light my-3'>Go Back</Link>
    <Row>
        <Col md={6}>
             <Image src={product.image} alt={product.name} fluid />
        </Col>

        <Col md={3}>
            <ListGroup variant="flush">
                <ListGroup.Item>
                    <h3>{product.name}</h3>
                </ListGroup.Item>

                <ListGroup.Item>
                    <Rating value={product.rating} text={'${product.numReviews} reviews'} color={'#f8e825'} ></Rating>
                    </ListGroup.Item>
                <ListGroup.Item>
                    Price: ₹{product.price}
                </ListGroup.Item>

                <ListGroup.Item>
                    Description: {product.description}
                </ListGroup.Item>
            </ListGroup>
        </Col>
        
        <Col md={3}>
            <Card>
                <ListGroup variant="flush">
                    <ListGroup.Item>
                        <Row>
                            <Col>Price:</Col>
                            <Col>
                                <strong>{product.price}</strong>
                            </Col>
                        </Row>
                    </ListGroup.Item>
                    
                    <ListGroup.Item>
                        <Row>
                            <Col>Status:</Col>
                            <Col>
                               {product.countInStok > 0 ? 'In Stock' : 'Out of Stock'}
                            </Col>
                        </Row>
                    </ListGroup.Item>

                    <ListGroup.Item>
                        <Button className='btn-block' type='button'> add to Cart </Button>
                    </ListGroup.Item>

                </ListGroup>
            </Card>
        </Col>
    </Row>
</div>);
```

Comment: but is not showing products